# TFS -Source Control Repository Size Limit

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I was just wondering about the storage size limit of TF Service Source control repository in Free Plan.

We are using Team Foundation Service Free plan as we have only 4 users at the moment. I have checked the [tfs.visualstudio.com](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/pricing/information/) pricing and it doesn't say anything about the Source control storage limit. (What it includes)

1. Up to 5 users
2. Unlimited number of projects
3. Version control (TFVC or Git)
4. Work item tracking
5. Agile planning tools
6. Feedback management
7. Build (still in preview)
8. Test management (still in preview)

We check in loads of audio files which are required by the application (so far it is 2Gig of audio files + source files). So we are just wondering what is going to happen if we keep checking in audio files? *Please don't answer with same information that we already have knew about* - Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

There is no mention on site and in the FAQ. As this [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/86a7efb0-db1f-4fd7-ba3e-2e947a1bfb10/repository-size) from Microsoft from msdn forum says:

"There currently is no enforced limit. This may change in the future.
Trevor Hancock (Microsoft)"
Tuesday, March 05, 2013 6:52 PM

Comment: @kleopatra I changed answer a little, but it's the only content from msdn forum :)

Comment: ahh, it was a citation :-) Thanks for the clarification!